# Module not found in node-webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I recently started to play with node-webkit and tried to create a simple HelloWorld + load a module.
The module I chose to test was the 'getmac' (https://www.npmjs.org/package/getmac).

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var gm = require('getmac');
    </script>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi!</h1>
    We are using node.js <script>document.write(process.version)</script>.
  </body>
</html>
```

I installed the module normally with npm install and there is a node_modules folder inside my app folder. ALL MY RESOURCES are inside the folder (there are no other folders, except for node_modules -> that means no tree structure).
When I run this code I get a "module not found" error. I also read something about re-building modules with nw-gyp but I don't even know if it's necessary in this case (please include something about this in the answer if possible).
 Anyway, thanks for all the help. 

**NOTE**: the helloworld DOES work without trying to load the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when zipping everything. There was no error with the module.
I forgot to add the -r when zipping, therefore the subdirs were not included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to generate the correct js file to load in the browser. From the getmac page it looks like it should support it. [Here's](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires) how you can generate the js file.

Comment: Thank you, this got me started, but I'm still unable to make it work. I installed the browserify with npm and then ran inside node_modules/: browserify -r getmac > getmac.js . That successfully output a getmac.js file, which I was able to include in my html. But when I try to call the API it gives out an error (Uncaught Node error). Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I also ran into this  https://github.com/rhiokim/node-webkit-test/tree/master/get-mac-addres , which is exactly what I ws trying to build. It does NOT seem that the author used browserify for this. I was also unable to run his project, got the same error as I did before.

Comment: For anyone wondring this, you DO NOT NEED TO BROSERIFY for this module. Thanks for the help, though.